# I want to get it from the files array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

If I upload the file array Image,
I want to do something with each file.
So I put Image[] in Postman and get it to function,
But it occurs an error.
I do something or select the files in first file in array,is it right $_FILES['Image'][0]? or different select?

If you know about it, Please help me

[image]

[image]

---

Update

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++){
            $file = $_FILES['Image']['name'][$i];

            $ImagePath = $this->utils->sendFile($file);
        }
```

I use this just copy it and paste and it occurs error message like this

Illegal tmp_name string

Comment: change from `$_FILES['Image'][1]` to `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Comment: @KundanPrasad I have question about it, If I select 2nd files in array, how I can select it? and $_FILEs['Image'] does not need 'Image' String? if did it, undefined index of it.

Comment: 1st file `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` -> 2nd file `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`[1]

Comment: @KundanPrasad I get this message of it-> Undefined index: file |
I change it to Image?

Comment: And I change it image,  "message": "Unable to open /tmp/3abe3ec9cd6d5fd2e4ac0022b2564f7b.directory using mode r: fopen(/tmp/3abe3ec9cd6d5fd2e4ac0022b2564f7b.directory): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Comment: wait for my answer..

Comment: @PolarisNation add code not image of your code next time here how https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Sorry I will keep in mind

Comment: I am not sure that uploading image using api is good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this, i am sure it helps

```
$arr = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr) ; $i++)
    {
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'][$i];  

        $responce = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "orders/".$file_name);

    }
```

Comment: I have a message for it
Message:  move_uploaded_file(orders/testscreenshot1.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: first you need to create orders directory on root,
where your php action file is located. 
and in that directory your image will be upload

Comment: Thanks make root direcotry and try it, success. you save my day

Answer (score 0):

you can select file from postman by, image[0], image[1]
and then you can take files array to controller by

```
$count = count($FILES['image']['name']);
for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++){
    $file = $FILES['image']['name'][$i];
}
```

now you can pass this $file variable to move_uploaded_file() function oe in any other method.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I have problem It occurs the message -> Illegal string offset 'tmp_name'

Comment: why you use temp_name you can upload image by  $FILES['image']['name']    using only name, or you have to use temp_name you can use like $FILES['image'][temp_'name'] because your input file name is image.

Comment: for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++){
      $file = $_FILES['Image']['name'][$i];

      $ImagePath = $this->utils->sendFile($file);
  }

Comment: but first you need to count how many file are in upload queue,
$count = count($FILES['image']['name']);